# Ratingbar's last star is getting cropped

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm showing each user rating with a RecyclerView. But my last star in rating bar is cropped although I have enough space. Sample image is shown here [image: ratting cropped]

```xml
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/review_user_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Shahrear Bin Amin rated it"/>

                <RatingBar
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/each_user_rating"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:numStars="5"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove padding to the left. Instead, put marginStart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `marginStart` instead of using `paddingLeft` on the `RatingBar`

```
<RatingBar
    android:marginStart="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/each_user_rating"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"/>
```